# In Django, how can use build properties?

Tags: python, django

In python django framework,

I want to use different database connection property on local, alpha, release environment.

For example..

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'mydb',
    'USER': 'scott',
    'PASSWORD': 'tiger',
    'HOST': '${host}',
    'PORT': '${port}',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'threaded': True,
    }
},
```

}

But I can't find right way. Is there any good way?

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple `settings` modules.

```
myproject/
    settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        dev.py
        alpha.py
        prod.py
```

Use `myproject.settings.base` as an "abstract" base you can import in all "concrete" module. For instance:

```
from .base import *

DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
    'threaded': False,
}
```

Then, on each environment, set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to the right settings module (for instance: `myproject.settings.dev`).

Or call `manage.py` with the `--settings` option:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=myproject.settings.alpha
```

Comment: thanks, i found document also.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings